# how to compress mp3 file from php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, laravel-5.4

I am using both commands in my controller, but sometimes they are not working properly.
Sometimes the compressed file size is larger than size of the original file.

```
exec(FFmpeg -i old.mp3 -ab 64 mp3 newfile.mp3)
```

And

```
exec(ffmpeg -i old.mp3 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 48k new.mp3)
```

Please, help me.

Comment: Why do you think the resulting file should always be smaller? The original can be compressed with worse/different settings which result in a smaller file. Have you looked at the files’ information when this happens and compared to yours?

Comment: Not a PHP/Laravel problem though. Find correct settings for compression in ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above both command is different:

Option Description

- **-ab bitrate** : set audio bitrate (in kbit/s)
- **-acodec codec** : force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)

That's why In the first command set audio stream in 64 bit, and in the second command is do the stream copy to copy.

I hope this helps.